# Publish Qt app to Nokia Ovi Store

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia, s60, ovi

I have developed a symbian app for S60 mobile phones. I have signed the app from Nokia. But when I attempt to upload the app to Ovi Store, The following error occurs.

Errors
105 - The package UID is not valid: 0xe0071385.
106 - The exe/dll UID3 is not valid: 0xe0beeb65.
107 - The exe/dll SID is not valid: 0xe0beeb65.

My app Uid is valid, because signing the app was successful. In page http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Guide_to_Publishing_Qt_Applications_to_the_Ovi_Store it is clearly said that "Version number must match the version string displayed in the application. #{"My application installer"},(0x2002CCCF),1,0,0" and in my app, it is maintained.

Comment: "There is no such option", sorry, I did not understand which option you were saying.

Comment: It was supposed to be a comment to another post. Please ignore it.